# How to delete items one by one if the ID is the same ?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm developing shopping cart and when I add items two of the same ID and when I click to delete one of them , then it delets both items. How to delete them one by one ? I'm developing with Laravel.

This is the delete function:

```
public function delete(Request $request, $id)
{
    $products = session('cart');
    foreach ($products as $key => $value)
    {
        if ($value['id'] == $id)
        {
            unset($products [$key]);
        }
    }

    $request->session()->remove('cart');
    Session::forget('ticket');
    $request->session()->put('cart',$products);

    flash()->success('Prekė buvo sėkmingai pašalinta iš krepšelio.');
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Comment: Why do you have 2 items with the same ids....?

Comment: how you define the differences between the 2 ID-s?

Comment: Do a `break` after you unset this will remove the first product with that ID **but** its typical to have unique ids and a quantity rather than multiple products of the same ID. (just something to think about).

Comment: Hmm... there is item in the shop. And I can write text on it. So I can add them with different texts on them. But they remain same id as in DB

Comment: You have to find a way to insert them on the db with different ID-s because you will face this problems

Comment: ID's are suppose to be unique, I'd strongly recommend that you keep the ID field unique and instead use a reference_id field (or something similar), you're gonna have multiple issues if you are unable to single out values in your database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you don't stop the loop, you will end up `unset`ing all products with that ID. Do the following:

```
public function delete(Request $request, $id)
{
    $products = session('cart');
    foreach ($products as $key => $value) {
        if ($value['id'] == $id) {
            unset($products [$key]);
            break;
        }
    }

    $request->session()->remove('cart');
    Session::forget('ticket');
    $request->session()->put('cart',$products);

    flash()->success('Prekė buvo sėkmingai pašalinta iš krepšelio.');
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

However since you are also adding extra text on items I suggest you be more specific on which one you need to delete:

```
public function delete(Request $request, $id, $text)
{
    $products = session('cart');
    foreach ($products as $key => $value) {
        if ($value['id'] == $id && $value['text'] == $text) {
            unset($products[$key]);
            break;
        }
    }

    $request->session()->remove('cart');
    Session::forget('ticket');
    $request->session()->put('cart',$products);

    flash()->success('Prekė buvo sėkmingai pašalinta iš krepšelio.');
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

The second suggestion is just speculation on my part. The idea is your real item `$id` is composed of the database ID and the text, these 2 should uniquely identify the product.